# Python3-Pip install issues broken packages

Tags: ubuntu

Let me start by saying I have limited experience with Linux and this very well may be an easy to answer question.

My dilemma is I am attempting to install hangups through the terminal 
sudo apt-get install python3-pip 
upon entering this command I receive this message in error
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.2-2ubuntu0.1) but 8.1.2-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Prior it was Recommending to install setuptools, dev, and whl, as well within that same error message, but I was able to remedy that by searching through multiple threads, which piggybacking off of that point I have done a solid two to three hours of research on this topic scouring threads on different websites, but nothing seems to be working. If anyone has any suggestions please chime in.

*I am running the most recent version of Kubuntu btw if that accounts for anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the output for `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`?

Comment: I have not, is that exactly how I would execute the command? dpkg --get-selections | grep hold?

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
  sudo apt-get install curl
  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10+ and Fedora 13+ have a package called python3-pip which will install pip-3.2 (or pip-3.3, pip-3.4 or pip3 for newer versions) without needing this jumping through hoops.

I came across this and fixed this without needing the likes of wget or virtualenvs (assuming Ubuntu 12.04):

```
Install package python3-setuptools: run sudo aptitude install python3-setuptools, this will give you the command easy_install3.
Install pip using Python 3's setuptools: run sudo easy_install3 pip, this will give you the command pip-3.2 like kev's solution.
Install your PyPI packages: run sudo pip-3.2 install <package> (installing python packages into your base system requires root, of course).
…
Profit!
```

pretty sure this did it for me

credit akaIDIOT